# MPMoviePlayerController showing white background only

Tags: ios, avfoundation, mpmovieplayercontroller

in my app i want to play a video in an MPMoviePlayerController, but when i run the app it shows me only a white frame. here's the code:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"Problems" ofType:@"MP4"];
NSLog(@"path: %@", moviePath);
//NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 700);
player.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.detailView addSubview:player.view];
[player play];
```

Edit: i tried this code instead and added an @property for the MPMoviePlayerController. i can see now the player but the app crashes and the breakpoint couldn't identify where. here's the code:

```
self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Problems" ofType:@"MP4"]]];
[self.player.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];

[self.detailView addSubview:self.player.view];
[self.player play];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method 'presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:':

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.player];
```